# How to work with unionTypes in angular html with strict Typescript linting

Tags: angular, typescript, lint

Our Angular app version 14 recently upgrade to work with Typescript 4.7.2 and the angular/cli compiler checks has introduced some breaking changes that currently we can't find a fix to.

One of the following issues is as follows:

```
    interface UnionType { 
      name: string;
      type: 'tester' | 'developer';
    }

    interface Tester extends UnionType { 
      name: string;
      type: 'tester';
      information: string;
    }

    interface Developer extends UnionType { 
      name: string;
      type: 'developer';
      tools: string;
    }
```

Our issue with this is that we have in our Typescript a variable that could potentially be both of them. I.e:

```
public array: (Tester | Developer)[];
```

and a html:

```
<div *ngFor="let unionType of array">
   <div *ngIf="unionType.type === 'tester'">
      {{ unionType.information }}
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="unionType.type === 'developer'">
      {{ unionType.tools }}
   </div>
</div>
```

In this example, the compiler is giving errors "Property 'information' does not exist on type 'Developer'."

And also "Property 'tools ' does not exist on type 'Tester'."

If this would to be Typescript I could do if instanceof, which I find it a bad usage when doing in html. Has anyone came across a similar issue?

Edit: Further example to explain my current situation.

```
<div *ngFor="let unionType of array">
   <div *ngIf="unionType.type === 'tester'">
      <display-tester [tester]="unionType"></display-tester>
   </div>
</div>

export class DisplayTester {
   @Input() public tester: Tester;
}
```

This would also give an error that the variable type 'Tester | Developer' cannot be given to variable 'Tester'. In this case, the variable unionType could be potentially Developer or Tester but with the if in the html guaranties it could only be a Tester, even so, there's a compiler error.

Edit: After a suggested stackoverflow comment I was able to figure out this issue.

The issue was as follows

```
class UnionType { 
  name: string;
  type: 'tester' | 'developer';
}

class Tester extends UnionType { 
  name: string;
  type = 'tester';
  information: string;
}

class Developer extends UnionType { 
  name: string;
  type = 'developer';
  tools: string;
}
```

When using class and inheriting the UnionType and giving the value 'tester' or 'developer' the html:

```
   <div *ngIf="unionType.type === 'tester'">
      <display-tester [tester]="unionType"></display-tester>
   </div>
```

Was giving errors because even though the if was checking tester, the compiler thought it could be any of the two object types. To fix this it was in the typings:

From:

```
class Tester extends UnionType { 
  name: string;
  type = 'tester';
  information: string;
}
```

To:

```
class Tester extends UnionType { 
  name: string;
  type: 'tester' = 'tester';
  information: string;
}
```

Even if by instances the value would always be 'tester' the typing in theory could be 'tester' | 'developer', this generated the issue that the compiler couldn't manage out to understand the instance. Now with this typing it understand that if the object has the type  'tester' it knows that it is of the class Tester.

Comment: Your `Developer` type has a property `type` whose type is still `"tester"`.

Comment: no error on Angular 14.2 - see [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-berbvd?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Allen for the Stackbliz, it really helped. It was true that it didn't give errors, I kept adapting your example until I found the solution (which is edited in the post now)

Answer (score 0):

Note you can post an answer to your own question if you think it'll help others in future.

Per the updates to the question, you're using a `class` to instantiate an object that implements the interface.

This means `type = 'tester'` won't work because `'tester'` is a string and type is a union of two string *values*.

Instead of the following (which does work but I don't recommend)

```
class Tester extends UnionType { 
  name: string;
  type: 'tester' = 'tester';
  information: string;
}
```

I suggest the following.

```
type DeveloperType = 'tester' | 'developer'; // create alias for the union type

class Tester extends UnionType { 
  name: string;
  type: DeveloperType = 'tester';
  information: string;
}
```

This make is clear where  `= 'tester'` is coming from and what the alternatives are.

Optionally you can make an enum

```
enum DeveloperEnum = {
    TESTING = 'testing',
    DEVELOPER = 'developer'
}

class Tester extends UnionType { 
  name: string;
  type: DeveloperEnum = DeveloperEnum.TESTING;
  information: string;
}
```

These require updating the interface model with `type: DeveloperType` or `type: DeveloperEnum`.